Path-Connected Spaces are Locally Embeddable into R^\alpha
Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a path-connected space. I thought that it must be true that for every point $x$ in $X$ there must be some ordinal $\alpha$ and some neighborhood  $x\in U$ such that $U$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{\alpha}$, but the trivial topology (and topology without sufficient separation) is a counterexample. Is there some separation axiom such that $X$ having this axiom gives X this “local embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{\alpha}$” property (eg, does $X$ being $T_4$ do the trick)?

Do yoy equip $\mathbb R^\alpha$ with the product topology?

Does it have a special reason that you consider ordinals instead of cardinals? If $\mathbb R^\alpha$ is equipped with the product topology, it is the same as just considering cardinals, and this is the usual approach.

A topological space can be embedded into $\mathbb R^\alpha$ for some cardinal (equivalently, ordinal) $\alpha$ with the product topology, iff the space is completely regular, $T_2$. This has nothing to do with path-connectness.

@Ulli There’s no particular reason for using ordinals instead of cardinals. Could you briefly explain why the “completely regular, T2” result is true or maybe point me to a source?

This is a standard result that you will find in certainly any introductory book on topology, for instance Engelking, General topology, 2.3.23.
